# Express Parsing Array from POST

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

Running an Express API, I'm struggling to parse data including an array of objects correctly when hitting a POST route.

A simplified version of the code -

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var parseUrlencoded = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

router.post('/', parseUrlencoded, function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

Hitting the API with the following

```
{ name: "Object name", 
  arrayOfObjects: [
      { name: "Sub Object Name", subType: "Sub Object Type" }, 
      { name: "Sub Object Name 2", subType: "Sub Object Type 2" }
  ] 
}
```

Logs out

```
{ name: "Object name", 
  'arrayOfObjects[0][name]': "Sub Object Name",
  'arrayOfObjects[0][subType]': "Sub Object Type",
  'arrayOfObjects[1][name]': "Sub Object Name 2",
  'arrayOfObjects[1][subType]': "Sub Object Name",
}
```

I would like to receive this as an array, which is the case when using a PUT request.

I'm sure this possible using a configuration of bodyParser or similar, but I'm struggling to find a good solution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok, from your question I understand that you want to manipulate the POST Body like a json array then use **qs library**  by making **extended** **true**

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Answer (score 6):

You can send an *string* instead of *array* and keep the `extended` option in false.

**From your front js:**

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
$.ajax("/send", {
     data: { "strArr": fruits.join() },
     type: "POST",
     async: true,
 ......
```

**From your server js:**

```
router.post('/send', function(req, res) {
    var fruits = req.body.strArr.split(",");
    console.log(fruits); // This is an array
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the second part of your object so that Node converts it from string to array.

```
JSON.parse(req.body.arrayOfObjects);
```

will return you the wanted array for the second part of your object

Answer (score 0):

change extended option to `true` it will refrain from turning it to a json