# Mongoose Schema Array Property on Document Keeps Changing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a Mongoose schema like such:

```
let mySchema = new Schema ({
    _myArray: [{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }]
})
```

I'm able to successfully create and update documents with a single value in the array.

```
await req.mySchema.update(req.body);
```

But the strange thing is that `_myArray` on `req.body` is undefined. Instead, it looks like this  when there is a single string in the array:

```
{
    '_myArray[]': "foo"
}
```

And like this when there are multiple strings in the array:

```
{
    '_myArray[]': ["foo", "bar"]
}
```

If I want to update `_myArray`, I need to manipulate the document so that the `_myArray` property exists.

```
req.body._myArray = req.body['_myArray[]']
await req.mySchema.update(req.body);
```

**Why does the document property name change from `_myArray` to `_myArray[]`?**

**How can I save an array of strings to a document without manually manipulating the document to add back the correct property `_myArray`?**

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an issue with Mongoose, it is a parsing issue with Express.

The solution is to use bodyParser with `extended` set to `TRUE`.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

[Express Parsing Array from POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46102660/express-parsing-array-from-post)